# Looking for derivative script

Tags: javascript, math

I am desperately looking for a JavaScript that can calculate the first derivative of a function. The function always includes only one variable, x.

> ```
> e.g. f(x) = x²
>   f'(3) = 2x
> ```

Consequently, the script should deliver the result  6, since `2*3 = 6`.

I hope you know what I mean.

Comment: "A function"?  What kind?  Polynomials only?  Trigonometric functions?  Transcendental functions?  Linear combinations of all of them?

Comment: Nah, forgot to mention. It can be any kind of function.

Comment: 3^2 is 9, is that what u are trying to do?

Comment: @lbu : see "derivative of a function". y = x^2 => derivative : 2*x => f(3) = 2 * 3 => 6

Comment: Do callers of this function know an appropriate epsilon to pass in so that you can just sample and compute?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a Java library to help do such a thing:

http://jscl-meditor.sourceforge.net/

And another:

http://www.mathtools.net/Java/Mathematics/index.html

You can always use Rhino and import Java classes to use in your JavaScript.

Here's one for JavaScript:

http://code.google.com/p/smath/wiki/smathJavaScriptAPI

Answer (score 10):

```
function slope (f, x, dx) {
    dx = dx || .0000001;
    return (f(x+dx) - f(x)) / dx;
}

var f = function (x) { return Math.pow(x, 2); }

slope(f, 3)
```

Comment: Not very helpful for functions that aren't analytic or have singularities or discontinuities.

Comment: `.00000009` better than `.0000001`

Answer (score 3):

Try [nerdamer](https://github.com/jiggzson/nerdamer/) .

It can do derivatives and build JavaScript functions with it.

```js
//Derivative of x^2
var result = nerdamer('diff(x^2,x)').evaluate();
document.getElementById('text').innerHTML = "<p>f'(x)="+result.text()+'</p>';
//Build a new function
var f = result.buildFunction();
//Evalute f'(3)
document.getElementById('text').innerHTML += "<p>f'(3)="+f(3).toString()+'</p>';
```

```html
<!-- Use https -->
<script src="https://nerdamer.com/js/nerdamer.core.js"></script>
<script src="https://nerdamer.com/js/Algebra.js"></script>
<script src="https://nerdamer.com/js/Calculus.js"></script>
<div id="text"></div>
```

Comment: thats the best answer

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is any in javascript.

Here is some simple solution, you need to adjust the code accordingly:

```
var func = function(x) {return Math.pow(x, 2)}
function der(x, func, prec, isLeft){
    if(prec == undefined) prec = 0.000000001;
    var y = func(x);
    if(isLeft){
        var x1 = x - prec;
    } else {
        x1 = x + prec;
    }
    var y1 = func(x1);
    return (y1-y)/(x1-x);
}
```

Comment: isLeft => one-sided derivative : http://www.ies.co.jp/math/java/calc/limrl/limrl.html

Comment: Thanks, I'll have a look at it.

Answer (score 0):

You can do similar things using [diff.js](https://github.com/balint42/diff.js). You could do:

```
x = range(-10, 10, 0.01); // works only in latest browsers
f = diffXY(x, x.map(F));
```

which would give you the values of the derivative `f` of your function `F` at `x` = -10 to 10 with stepsize 0.01.

Answer (score 0):

[math.js](https://mathjs.org) looks pretty good for this job to me. Check out [this](https://mathjs.org/docs/reference/functions/derivative.html) example:

```js
math.derivative('x^2', 'x')                     // Node {2 * x}
math.derivative('x^2', 'x', {simplify: false})  // Node {2 * 1 * x ^ (2 - 1)
math.derivative('sin(2x)', 'x'))                // Node {2 * cos(2 * x)}
math.derivative('2*x', 'x').evaluate()          // number 2
math.derivative('x^2', 'x').evaluate({x: 4})    // number 8
const f = math.parse('x^2')
const x = math.parse('x')
math.derivative(f, x)                           // Node {2 * x}
```