# Are there any native functions to perform integration or derivatives in JS? 

Tags: javascript

Are there any Math functions for finding derivatives in javascript?

Comment: No. (15 char limit). You probably shouldn't do calculus in JavaScript.

Comment: Similar thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6399777/looking-for-derivative-script

Comment: And this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2870215/are-there-any-somewhat-advanced-mathematics-javascript-libraries

Answer (score 1):

mathjs its only library for math,

Answer (score 1):

Try [nerdamer](https://github.com/jiggzson/nerdamer/) .

The main build has derivatives but the integration branch has integration.

```js
//Derivative of sin(x^2) + log(x) - 23 + e^(cos(x))
var result = nerdamer('diff(sin(x^2)+log(x)-23+exp(cos(x)),x)').evaluate();
document.getElementById('text').innerHTML += '<p>'+result.text()+'</p>';
```

```html
<script src="http://nerdamer.com/js/nerdamer.core.js"></script>
<script src="http://nerdamer.com/js/Algebra.js"></script>
<script src="http://nerdamer.com/js/Calculus.js"></script>
<div id="text"></div>
```

Answer (score -1):

The problem with use JS to calculate any derivative function is JS accumulate error into every interation, that's mean your answer could be so much different than using another language like python as a reason the declarative variables.